# can i deploy botkit-cms to heroku?

Tags: node.js, heroku, botkit

i got the deployment for the botkit-anywhere but for the botkit-cms, the deployment from the nodejs show success but when running the app in heroku, the deployment is not success (show only "--Application error--").

Running local is fine, just going to the localhost:'somehwere' and access to botkit-cms.

i did the same deployment for both botkit-anywhere and botkit-cms.

Can i know how to deploy the botkit-cms on heroku? Is is valid or need to deploy it somewhere ?

Comment: Your "Application error" probably comes with an HTTP 500 response code. [HTTP 500](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_status_codes#5xx_Server_Error) is a generic server-side error message. On its own it barely tells us anything. Any time you see this your first step should be to check your error logs for more detail. Check your error logs with `heroku logs`.

Answer (score 0):

Botkit-cms currently reads and writes from the filesystem.  As a result, it is not compatible with Heroku.